# negative of "contains" in openrefine

Tags: openrefine, grel

I would like to add a column based on another column and fill it with all the values that do **NOT** contain "jpg"

so the negation of this:

```
filter(value.split(","), v, v.contains("jpg")).join("|")
```

How can I write "does not contain"?

Answer (score 2):

`contains` gives a boolean output i.e. true or false. So we have:

```
v = "picture.jpg" -> v.contains("jpg") = TRUE

v = "picture.gif" -> v.contains("jpg") = FALSE
```

`filter` finds all values in an array which return TRUE for whatever condition you use in the filter. There are a couple of ways you could filter an array to find the values that don't contain a string, but using contains the simplest is probably to use `not` to reverse the result of your condition:

```
filter(value.split(","), v, not(v.contains("jpg"))).join("|")
```